# How to access the browser history beyond the last 7 days of the default browser?

Tags: stock-browser, browser-history

I know it's possible to view the entire browser history in other browsers. I can only see the last 7 days of my browsing history. How can I see which sites I visited beyond just the last week? Or are those getting deleted?

**My phone**: Android 5.0, Samsung Galaxy S5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving this question up so that other people having the same issue may find help and in the case that someone knows a potentially better way to retrieve more of the browser-history.

I found something in:

```
/data/data/com.sec.android.app.sbrowser/files/ {1_tab123 files}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post but I thought an answer would be good for posterity.
The Samsung Internet browser is a Chromium based browser. As such it used to be you could use chrome commands from the address bar such as "chrome://history" and that would give access to the total history in the Samsung browser. Since the 2017 update to Samsung Internet 5.4 I have lost that functionality. It appears they have blocked it in the code.